# How to call Microsoft Graph APIs for Teams using user credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The requirement is to send a chat message to a channel in MS Teams using Graph APIs. The idea is to automate a workflow that when triggered sends a message to a channel mentioning a chatbot (e.g. @XXXbot hello).

Incoming webhook link feature provided out-of-the box by MS Teams can not be used as it lacks the @mention functionality.

So, the question is how can I create an automation framework that does the following as and when required:

- Authenticate/authorize every time I hit the API
- Sends chat messages to a channel in MS Teams

Given, I have already created an AAD user that I have used with [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and was able to send the message. I want to utilize the same credentials in my automation too.

I went through the MS docs but all of them are talking about registering an App in azure portal to achieve this e.g. here: [Auth concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts), so wondering if that's the only way or do we have any other way to achieve this purely through user credentials. I am fine with even if there are some curl commands to be made for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call Microsoft Graph, you have to register an App in azure portal.

Per my understanding, you want to use a user token (corresponding to application token) but you don't want interactively sign-in.

In this case, the only way is using [Resource Owner Password Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), which allows an application to sign in the user by directly handling their password.

[image]

We need to put our password into the request. Therefore, it is inevitable to bear certain security risks.

Please note that:

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios,
> more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow
> requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries
> risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this
> flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

But based on your requirement, the only way is using this flow. Take it as your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for to-the-point answer. Yes, I am aware of the security risk associated with this approach but anyway we need to store the credentials in GitHub secrets, so safe from storage per se.

However, I still don't understand why we need an app to be registered. I am curious to know how Graph Explorer is working behind the hood as it does not uses any client id/secret but only user id/pwd and potentially Access token that we can see on the dashboard (Access Token tab). Can't we utilize such communication from our application?

Comment: @Bhoj Microsoft Graph Explorer also uses an app registration which is created in MS tenant as a multi-tenant app. When you sign into Graph Explorer, you need to do the admin consent for your tenant (or user content), which will add the multi-tenant enterprise app into your tenant. You can copy the access token from Microsoft Graph explorer and decode it in https://jwt.ms to see the client-id of the app registration. So it's the same.

Comment: That exactly gives me a good insight on the Graph explorer's working, Thanks!